# (How) can multiple backreference be used in alternation patterns?

Tags: r, regex

This question is a spin-off from that question [Function to count of consecutive digits in a string vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70529251/function-to-count-of-consecutive-digits-in-a-string-vector).

Assume I have strings such as `x`:

```
x <- c("555123", "57333", "21112", "12345", "22144", "44440")
```

and want to detect those strings where any number between `2` and `5` occurs in immediate duplication as many times as itself. That is, match if the string contains `22`, `333`, `4444`, and `55555`.

If I approach this task in small chunks using backreference, everything is fine:

```
str_detect(x, "(2)\\1{1}")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE** FALSE

str_detect(x, "(3)\\1{2}")
[1] FALSE  **TRUE** FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

str_detect(x, "(4)\\1{3}")
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE**
```

However, if I pursue a **single solution** for all matches using a vector with the allowed numbers:

```
digits <- 2:5
```

and an alternation pattern, such as this:

```
patt <- paste0("(", digits, ")\\1{", digits - 1, "}", collapse = "|")
patt
[1] "(2)\\1{1}|(3)\\1{2}|(4)\\1{3}|(5)\\1{4}"
```

and input `patt` into `str_detect`, this only detects the first alternative, namely `(2)\\1{1}`:

```
str_detect(x, patt)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  **TRUE** FALSE
```

Is it the backreference which cannot be used in alternation patterns? If so, then why does a `for` loop iterating through each option **separately** not work either?

```
res <- c()
for(i in 2:5){
  res <- str_detect(x, paste0("(", i, ")\\1{", i - 1, "}"))
}
res
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Advice on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the backreferences should also be incremented as you have more groups as well `(2)\1|(3)\2{2}|(4)\3{3}|(5)\4{4}`

Comment: Yes, brilliant! This pattern works: `paste0("(", digits, ")\\", c(1, digits), "{", digits - 1, "}", collapse = "|")`. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I have posted an answer about the regex. There might be better answers posted with an R solution, as my knowledge about R is at a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern `(2)\\1{1}|(3)\\1{2}|(4)\\1{3}|(5)\\1{4}` the quantifier repeats matching the backreference to the first capture group. That is why you only match the first alternative.

You could repeat the next capture group instead as there are multiple groups.

```
(2)\\1{1}|(3)\\2{2}|(4)\\3{3}|(5)\\4{4}
```

The `(2)\\1{1}` can be just `(2)\\1` but this is ok as you assembling the pattern dynamically

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
> grepl(
+   paste0(sapply(2:5, function(i) sprintf("(%s)\\%s{%s}", i, i - 1, i - 1)), collapse = "|"),
+   x
+ )
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

or

```
> rowSums(sapply(2:5, function(i) grepl(sprintf("(%s)\\1{%s}", i, i - 1), x))) > 0
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe you can say a word or two about `sprintf`, which I'm not familiar with

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `sprintf` prints a string with a given format, where `%s` refers to the value you want to fill into the format. You can try `?sprintf` to read more about this function.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to update the regex:

```
patt = paste0(
  "(", digits, ")\\", digits - 1, "{", digits - 1, "}", 
  collapse = "|"
)
str_detect(x, patt)
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

In your `for` loop, you are replacing `res` each time so when you print `res` at the end, you are seeing the result for when `i` is 5. If you use `print()` instead:

```
for(i in 2:5){
  print(str_detect(x, paste0("(", i, ")\\1{", i - 1, "}")))
}
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

If you wanted to use a loop:

```
map_lgl(x, function(str) {
  any(map_lgl(
    2:5, 
    ~ str_detect(str, paste0("(", .x, ")\\1{", .x - 1, "}"))
  ))
})
```

Output:

```
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: A brilliant comprehensive answer. I have not accepted it because the trick was mentioned in a comment prior to your post.